# Webapp with GWT in my own server and GAE backend

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, web-applications, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've set up a simple web app with GWT + GAE with Java backend (pretty much like the stockwatcher example in the tutorial: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html). It works fine when served from the .appspot.com domain.

I would like to be able to serve the client (GWT) part from a different server (local web server in my PC for now) and still use GAE as Backend. How can this be done?

**Attempted solution**

I thik this adds up to doing cross server Ajax, I have not found much information on how to do this, so I proceeded by trial and error; here is what I've done:

The client-side app is called *myapp_web*, the server side is called *myapp*.

I copied the GWT part to my local server, in the directory */webapps/myapp_web*; it loaded fine. I got a 404 error on */webapps/myapp_web/myapp*, so I deduced this is the url where the app tries to find the backend.

I found in http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html an example PHP script which is supposed to serve as a proxy to allow the cross server call:

```
<?php

// PHP Proxy example for Yahoo! Web services. 
// Responds to both HTTP GET and POST requests
//
// Author: Jason Levitt
// December 7th, 2005
//

// Allowed hostname (api.local and api.travel are also possible here)
define ('HOSTNAME', 'http://search.yahooapis.com/');

// Get the REST call path from the AJAX application
// Is it a POST or a GET?
$path = ($_POST['yws_path']) ? $_POST['yws_path'] : $_GET['yws_path'];
$url = HOSTNAME.$path;

// Open the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
if ($_POST['yws_path']) {
    $postvars = '';
    while ($element = current($_POST)) {
        $postvars .= urlencode(key($_POST)).'='.urlencode($element).'&';
        next($_POST);
    }
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
}

// Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Make the call
$xml = curl_exec($session);

// The web service returns XML. Set the Content-Type appropriately
header("Content-Type: text/xml");

echo $xml;
curl_close($session);

?>
```

I copied this script into */webapps/myapp_web/myapp*, file *myapp*, no extension, and I got Apache to handle it as php. I changed the variable *HOSTNAME* from  *http://search.yahooapis.com/* to *http://myapp_url.appspot.com/myapp_web/myapp*.

Now I get 500 server error and I'm stuck, not knowing how to debug this. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: That error must be because you are not considering `X-GWT-Permutation` header, take a look to my edited response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say in your question, there are two options to deal with this:

- First option is to setup correctly your server side (GAE app) to handle correctly Cross-origin resource sharing ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). This only works with browsers supporting it. Most browser does nowadays included IE10. IE8/9 need a different approach [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- And the second one is to use a proxy in server side like the one you tried. But you must compose the request server adding the `X-GWT-Permutation` coming from your client. Otherwise gwt servlets will raise a `SecurityException` causing a 500 response.

Said that, I would go ahead with the CORS option because its simplicity, lightweight, and it is going to be the standard way.

To configure CORS, you just have to setup a filter in your web application.

Adding these lines to your `web.xml` file:

```xml
<filter>
 <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>my.namespace.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And coding a servlet filter to handle requests, and respond with the appropriate headers.

Here you have an example I wrote some time ago for the [gwt-query ajax wiki](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29).

```java
 public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
   // For security reasons set this regex to an appropriate value
   // example: ".*example\\.com"
   private static final String ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP = ".*";

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
       ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
       throws IOException, ServletException {

     HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
     HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

     String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
     if (origin != null && origin.matches(ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP)) {
       resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
       if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
         resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
         if (origin != null) {
           String headers = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
           String method = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
           resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
           resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
           resp.setContentType("text/plain");
         }
         resp.getWriter().flush();
         return;
       }
     }

    // Fix ios6 caching post requests
    if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
      resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }

    if (filterChain != null) {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
  }

  @Override public void destroy() {}
  @Override public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

In your client code you have to set the full url to access your server, but it depends on what kind of ajax you are using (RPC, RequestFactory, RequestBuilder, etc).

In the case you were using RPC, you have to do this:

```java
 GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

 ((ServiceDefTarget)greetingService)
     .setServiceEntryPoint("http://mygaeapp.appspot.com/mymodule/greet");
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the right solution. However, I tested it and now I obtain this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load myapp.appspot.com/myapp_web/myapp. Origin mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I found this might be caused by a missing http header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I changed **resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)** to **resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")**; but I don't get it to work. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: try to debug the trafic using firebug or chrome developer tools and take a look to headers. You should see first an OPTIONS request and then a POST one. They should have set the appropriate headers from server.

Answer (score -1):

So is this making it to GAE at all?  Where are you getting the 500 error from?  GAE or local apache?  Does this run on the same hostname/port as your gwt server does?  If not you may be running afowl of your same origin policy.

I think the architecture you want would basically be this:

Browser -> GWT server (tomcat?) -> return gwt code

Browser -> GWT RPC calls to GWT server -> GWT Server calls GAE via services or rest calls -> GWT formats response and returns data to browser.

Though honestly I don't know why you want to separate the two.  It seems like you are just making this harder than necessary.